# lubuntu 14.04.5 kernel compile error

Tags: kernel, lubuntu

I have tried compile kernel with no changes and it returned error:

```
arch/x86/boot/compressed/head_32.o: In function `efi32_config':
(.data+0x58): undefined reference to `efi_call_phys'
make[3]: *** [arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux] Error 1
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux] Error 2
make[1]: *** [bzImage] Error 2
```

Comment: Hi kira!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please include in your question the commands you used to get and compile the kernel?  What kernel version are you attempting to compile and why?  Ubuntu comes with a patched kernel different from mainline, and there's information on compiling mainline kernels if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks for friendly comment. I compile kernel to add my system call functions. I already solved problem. thank you.

Comment: If you solve your problem, please add the solution as an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
Modify linux-source-3.13.0/arch/x86/boot/compressed/head_32.S file content:

```
    .data
efi32_config:
    .fill 11,8,0
    .long efi_call_phys
    .long 0
    .byte 0
```

As below:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_EFI_STUB
    .data
efi32_config:
    .fill 11,8,0
    .long efi_call_phys
    .long 0
    .byte 0
#endif
```

you can also find solution on:
https://kernel.opensuse.org/cgit/kernel/commit/?h=stable&id=3db4cafdfd05717dc939780134e53023a3c1f15f